# My terminal and filesystem are hanging on macOS when dealing with millions of files

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, freeze, copy

So I have had an external hard drive connected to my laptop, and have been writing millions of files to the external hard drive. One directory even has over 2 million folders at the first level deep.

Probably a dozen times my computer has frozen up. I have about 50+ windowed applications opened and every now and then my screen gets that nintendo glitch look to it where everything turns to lines and shakes. The glitching part doesn't cause the freezing, but something is causing it. When it freezes the spinner goes on forever and I have to press the power button to shut it off.

I leave it shut off for at least 15 seconds before turning it on again. When I start again, it gives me back all my windows as they were, except the terminal windows aren't in the right spot anymore, they're just at the home directory.

I say all this because now I can't even type `ls` inside `/Volumes`, it just hangs. I tried hard unplugging the hard drive and plugging it back in. It registers in the finder window as being present, but I simply can't do `ls /Volumes`. I can't `cd /Volumes` either. I can't go into the hard drive. This only started happening after I've been writing millions of files to it.

It's a Western Digital external hard drive.

Oh wait! There now `ls` has finally completed. It took about 10 minutes for it to register fully.

Hmm… Wondering if anyone might know why it's doing this? Why it's not letting me get into the drive until long time?

So okay, now I just started writing more files. It let me write a few thousand more but now it's hanging again. In these cases I can't <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to get out of the process, I have to open the Activity Monitor and force quit. But then it's back to I can't `ls` in the `/Volumes`. Wondering what the heck is going on.

I have also been typically running 3-5 processes all writing files in parallel.

Comment: Millions of individual files in just one directory is going to stress out most file systems. If you expect to write that many files can you somehow spread them over a bunch of directories?

Answer (score 2):

Like [the other answer states](https://superuser.com/a/1438638/167207), you just got too many files and should expect a 10 minute wait time when you go to mess with millions of files and folders. Try to search for a more efficient way to move them all, or just accept it's gonna take time.

Also, why do you have millions of folders?

Comment: Wondering if it makes any difference if I make the directories hold only a fixed amount like 1000 files/folders each, rather than 1 million, or if it's the sheer number of files/folders I have that is the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197162/ntfs-performance-and-large-volumes-of-files-and-directories

Answer (score 1):

I am not macOS savvy. However, as far as system slowness is concerned, having millions of files in a single folder *is* a cause for the computer to be slow in any computer system.

Every time the computer is requested to access the folder for a specific file, the hard drive searches the first through the last file in the directory to find the file in question. With many searches for a file or even *worse* the time between requesting a file and getting a file takes longer.

Say you are not accessing that huge folder. But if you have a service running that does something called indexing, it will access that folder from time to time. Those times being after your computer touches that folder.

Can you defragment that external drive? Or does macOS have a program to defragment? Does the drive have any notable problems? do you have a program like Windows does for checking the drive like [CHKDSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK)?